# Discord.js v14 - Delete a channel and recreate it with the same name

Tags: discord.js, purge

**Purge Channel Command**

I want to make a slash command that deletes the channel specified, then recreate it with the same name. Like this.

/purgechannel [channel]

I don't know how to make this.

I have tried but all of my code has been deleted due to broken code.

Comment: Please provide a snippet of code along with the issues you are facing. Ideally, you would simply want to store the channel name temporarily, delete the channel and recreate it.